# Asynchronous Calls and Recursion with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion

I'm looking to execute a callback upon the full completion of a recursive function that can go on for an undetermined amount of time.  I'm struggling with async issues and was hoping to get some help here.  The code, using the `request` module, is as follows:

```
var start = function(callback) {
  request.get({
    url: 'aaa.com'
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    var startingPlace = JSON.parse(body).id;
    recurse(startingPlace, callback);
  });
};

var recurse = function(startingPlace, callback) {
    request.get({
        url: 'bbb'
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        // store body somewhere outside these funtions
        // make second request
        request.get({
            url: 'ccc'
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            var anArray = JSON.parse(body).stuff;
            if (anArray) {
                anArray.forEach(function(thing) {
                    request.get({
                        url: 'ddd'
                    }, function(error, response, body) {
                        var nextPlace = JSON.parse(body).place;
                        recurse(nextPlace);
                    });
                })
            }
        });
    });
    callback();
};

start(function() {
    // calls final function to print out results from storage that gets updated each     recursive call
    finalFunction();
});
```

It seems that once my code goes past the `for` loop in the nested requests, it continues out of the request and ends the initial function call while the recursive calls are still going on.  I want it to not finish the highest-level iteration until all the nested recursive calls have completed (which I have no way of knowing how many there are).

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: you need to give stuff names, and you'll need an outer wrapper function around the parts shown wo that you can collect results/monitor progress.

Comment: You need to fix many things. (1) Change `recurse(nextPlace);` to `recurse(nextPlace, callback);` (2) If it is not an array in your test, recursion stops, so, right after the `if(anArray) {....}` write down `callback();` (3) Remove entirely the `callback();` that you have at the very bottom (4) In the comments part if you let anything asynchronous happen or if the execution stops you should pass appropriately or call (using `return callback();` this time) the callback function respectively. You are set. In any case, do (1) - (3) and you will let us know what is going on.

Comment: I only need the final function to be called once ALL recursion loops are complete.  This will call it after each loop has been completed.  My second concern, and larger concern, is how to make the HTTP requests blocking - right now, once they are called, the loop continues and does not wait for them to complete.  This is really what is making this problematic.

Comment: You are right and I was wrong above. You should then use async, for example, `async.parallel`, when you go over the array. For an example, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26431257/1355058 where I also wanted to pass different parameters to all the calls that happen in parallel. Now, you are set. :)

Comment: I'll check out the async module in a bit more detail.  Is there a particular function that works well with recursion?  I'll need the highest level `for` loop to complete last, so when I run the callback (I can pass it the condition to test if it is equal to `startingPlace`), I'm in the right spot?

Comment: For async look here: https://github.com/caolan/async . Go down to parallel, and run in parallel all those get requests for the elements of the array. However, now when you return using `callback();` you should indicate if there was an error because parallel expects to see an error in the first argument of the callback. Thus, make changes (1) and (3) and you will take care of (2) manually when all the functions return on the parallel call.

Comment: Yes you are (that's why I upvoted). Really, forget about this problem for now and try to create a minimal example using async, in particular `async.parallel`. Just don't forget to pass _an error value_ (just use `null` everywhere) as a parameter to the callback function. In other words, make your calls to the callback like `return callback(null);`. All these "errors" will be gathered by the different recursive calls of async.parallel (one for each array) and since none of them fails (all return `null`), then you get what you want. But do not forget changes (1) and (3) too.

Comment: I understand how `async.parallel` works, but I'm not sure how it will solve the issue of the HTTP requests not finishing before moving on with each of the items in the array. I'm able to use the function fine without making requests, but when that piece comes into play, things get trickier.

Comment: Also, I suggested parallel, because you can parallelize here, since there seem to be no dependencies between the elements of the array when you apply recursion.

Comment: All the `get` operations will happen asynchronously, so, almost all the calls will be issued "almost" together. However, it may take 10msecs for one of them to get a response, 3 secs for another and so on. Now, each such call will recurse before it returns. So, you will spawn many parallel such requests. Well, at some point you will stop spawning and then the functions start returning. Once _all_ the functions that were associated with a specific parallel request return, then you can move on and have a `return callback(null);` statement. Just don't forget the error code to notify async.

Comment: I understand that conceptually, but when I try and put that into practice, once the requests on one level complete, it moves onto the callback immediately without waiting for the recursive loops to complete.  Can you perhaps give a more concrete example with code, using the `if (anArray) {...}` block as the code to be replaced with `async.parallel`?  Thanks for all your help. Also I'm a bit unsure how I can use `async.parallel` with `for` loops that vary in length.  It seems like you need to declare your functions explicitly, rather than looping through with `parallel` (as opposed to `each`).

Comment: Ok, I just wrote the entire `recurse` function. As you can see we can prepare the calls that we want to perform in parallel before we issue `async.parallel`. The other catch here is that you have to use `bind` (with first argument `null`; that was in the link that I mentioned above), and then pass the parameters of the `get` functions that will be executed in parallel. The names that I had in my link were there because I tend to like giving names for a few such parallel calls. But you can perfectly well pass an array of functions and end of story. Anyway, I have a morning flight.

Comment: I edited the post again. This should work. I had to define a function `myGet`. The thing is that parallel is going to pass its own callback. So note below in the code that there is a `callback` mentioned in `myGet` (which will be passed by parallel) and a `callback2` mentioned in `recurse`.

Comment: Yep, this certainly does what you wanted. The only theoretical question that I have is how you guarantee that these recursive calls will end. But I guess you know better than me. Btw, this was an interesting problem because I could only do it with BFS as it is below, while my original idea which was closer to a DFS was not working. Anyway, I have to go.

Comment: Finally I also renamed to `error1`, `error2`, `error3` and `response1`, `response2`, and `body1` and `body2` the repetitions so that it is clear that these are values that are set from the callback of the `request.get` inside the `recurse`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example you have no recursive calls. If I understand correctly you want to say that `recurse(point, otherFunc);` is the beginning of a recursive call.

Then just go back to the definition of the recursive call (which you have not shown in your post) and do this (add a third argument for a callback function to be called in the end of recursion; the caller will pass it as a parameter):

```
function recurse(startingPlace, otherFunc, callback_one) {
    // code you may have ...
    if (your_terminating_criterion === true) {
         return callback_one(val); // where val is potentially some value you want to return (or a json object with results)
    }
    // more code you may have
}
```

Then in the original code that you posted, make this call instead (in the inner-most part):

```
recurse(startingPlace, otherFunc, function (results) {
    // results is now a variable with the data returned at the end of recursion
    console.log ("Recursion finished with results " + results);
    callback();   // the callback that you wanted to call right from the beginning
});
```

Just spend some time and try to understand my explanation. When you understand, then you will know node. This is the node philosophy in one post. I hope it is clear. Your very first example should look like this:

```
var start = function(callback) {
  request.get({
    url: 'aaa.com'
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    var startingPlace = JSON.parse(body).id;
    recurse(startingPlace, otherFunc, function (results) {
        console.log ("Recursion finished with results " + results);
        callback();
    });
  });
};
```

**Below is only additional information in case you are interested. Otherwise you are set with the above.**

Typically in node.js though, people return an error value as well, so that the caller knows if the function that was called has finished successfully. There is no big mystery here. Instead of returning just `results` people make a call of the form

```
return callback_one(null, val);
```

Then in the other function you can have:

```
recurse(startingPlace, otherFunc, function (recError, results) {
    if (recErr) {
         // treat the error from recursion
         return callback(); // important: use return, otherwise you will keep on executing whatever is there after the if part when the callback ends ;)
    }

    // No problems/errors
    console.log ("Recursion finished with results " + results);
    callback();   // writing down `return callback();` is not a bad habit when you want to stop execution there and actually call the callback()
});
```

**Update with my suggestion**

This is my suggestion for the recursive function, but before that, it looks like you need to define your own `get`:

```
function myGet (a, callback) {
    request.get(a, function (error, response, body) {
        var nextPlace = JSON.parse(body).place;
        return callback(null, nextPlace); // null for no errors, and return the nextPlace to async
    });
}

var recurse = function(startingPlace, callback2) {
    request.get({
        url: 'bbb'
    }, function(error1, response1, body1) {
        // store body somewhere outside these funtions
        // make second request
        request.get({
            url: 'ccc'
        }, function(error2, response2, body2) {
            var anArray = JSON.parse(body2).stuff;
            if (anArray) {
                // The function that you want to call for each element of the array is `get`.
                // So, prepare these calls, but you also need to pass different arguments
                // and this is where `bind` comes into the picture and the link that I gave earlier.
                var theParallelCalls = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
                    theParallelCalls.push(myGet.bind(null, {url: 'ddd'})); // Here, during the execution, parallel will pass its own callback as third argument of `myGet`; this is why we have callback and callback2 in the code
                }
                // Now perform the parallel calls:
                async.parallel(theParallelCalls, function (error3, results) {
                    // All the parallel calls have returned
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var nextPlace = results[i];
                        recurse(nextPlace, callback2);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return callback2(null);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Note that I assume that the `get` request for 'bbb' is always followed by a `get` request for 'ccc'. In other words, you have not hidden a return point for the recursive calls where you have the comments.

Comment: Thanks this makes things more clear, but still does not quite solve the issue.  It's not a single `if/else` - even if the array does not exist, it has to go through all arrays before finishing.  For example, if the startingPlace has three places off of it, even if the first and second places were empty, it would still have to go through the third place.  This calls the callback the first time it gets to an empty place.

Comment: Ok, I now see why you had the callback where you had it in the beginning. In the very beginning of recurse you will need another async for the three get requests. Each one of them will return a result (possibly empty) but all three of them will be executed. Only then you want to call the callback and not where I have it now. I assume that you want to call these functions in order. Then try a variant of async like waterfall where you can also pass the results of one function to the next.

Comment: Actually the more I think your comment the more I do not know what you really want to do. recurse performs two simple gets and potentially many in the third step. If one of the points in the results array is empty, just do no make the recursive call. The last option (which is the most likely) is to use the results array as starting point for another async.parallel call but this time on recurse (not myGet). Then when all of them return only then you have the statement 'return callback2();' and eliminate the else altogether. Makes sense?

Comment: It's very similar to a tree.  Each place has `x` number of next places.  I have to recurse through each place, making a `GET` request for each next place, etc. Finally, once ALL `GET` requests are finished, I have to make the final function call.  The callback is only executed once the last response is received, but there's no information about where that stopping point is. I've followed your code, using `async.parallel`, but have still had no luck.  I feel like there is something very fundamental I am missing here.  I've typically had no trouble with callbacks and async issues.

Comment: Was finally able to solve this using a different `async` method - thanks for recommending the module!

Answer (score 8):

Typically when you write a recursive function it will do *something* and then either call itself or return.

You need to define `callback` in the scope of the recursive function (i.e. `recurse` instead of `start`), and you need to call it at the point where you would normally return.

So, a hypothetical example would look something like:

```
get_all_pages(callback, page) {
    page = page || 1;
    request.get({
        url: "http://example.com/getPage.php",
        data: { page_number: 1 },
        success: function (data) {
           if (data.is_last_page) {
               // We are at the end so we call the callback
               callback(page);
           } else {
               // We are not at the end so we recurse
               get_all_pages(callback, page + 1);
           }
        }
    }
}

function show_page_count(data) {
    alert(data);
}

get_all_pages(show_page_count);
```

Comment: This was the best most concise answer for me. Thanks @Quentin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find [caolan/async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) useful. Look especially into `async.waterfall`. It will allow you to pass results from a callback from another and when done, do something with the results.

Example:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(cb) {
        request.get({
            url: 'aaa.com'
        }, function(err, res, body) {
            if(err) {
                return cb(err);
            }

            cb(null, JSON.parse(body).id);
        });
    },
    function(id, cb) {
        // do that otherFunc now
        // ...
        cb(); // remember to pass result here
    }
], function (err, result) {
   // do something with possible error and result now
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your recursive function is synchronous, just call the callback on the next line:

```
var start = function(callback) {
  request.get({
    url: 'aaa.com'
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    var startingPlace = JSON.parse(body).id;
    recurse(startingPlace, otherFunc);
    // Call output function AFTER recursion has completed
    callback();
  });
};
```

Else you need to keep a reference to the callback in your recursive function.

Pass the callback as an argument to the function and call it whenever it is finished.

```
var start = function(callback) {
  request.get({
    url: 'aaa.com'
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    var startingPlace = JSON.parse(body).id;
    recurse(startingPlace, otherFunc, callback);
  });
};
```

Comment: This is getting me closer, but I still have no way of figuring out when the recursive call is going to end exactly.  I don't have a set criteria for ending (I'm traversing something similar to a tree with an unspecified set of nodes), so I'm not exactly sure when to call the callback within the recursive function.  Thanks for this step in the right direction though.

Comment: Here's the full set of code.  I'm still having issues with the recursion, where I cannot get the program to wait for all the for loops and recursion to complete before calling the final function.  Using a setTimeout, everything works fine, so it's definitely an issue of asynchronicity, but obviously I cannot go that route.  I've updated the code above with more detail for additional help.

Answer (score 0):

Build your code from this example:

```
var udpate = function (callback){
    //Do stuff
    callback(null);
}

function doUpdate() {
    update(updateDone)
}

function updateDone(err) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    else
        doUpdate()
}

doUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

With **ES6**, **'es6-deferred'** & **'q'**. You could try as following,

```
var Q = require('q');
var Deferred = require('es6-deferred');

const process = (id) => {
    var request = new Deferred();

    const ids =//do something and get the data;
    const subPromises = ids.map(id => process(id));

    Q.all(subPromises).then(function () {
        request.resolve();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

    return request.promise
}

process("testId").then(() => {
    console.log("done");
});
```